# ¿ Como redimensionar imagen de fondo en Android programaticamente?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Estoy colocando una imagen de fondo en una Actividad obtenida desde la carpeta `drawable`, este es el código que implemento para dicha acción:

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.principal);
// Obtener la imagen desde Drawable
Drawable image  = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.alert);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    // Colocar la imagen de fondo de pantalla
    constraintLayout.setBackground(image);
}
```

Pero al ejecutarlo en el emulador se ve la imagen grande:

[Vista de la Imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfMQy.png)

Lo que deseo es redimensionar la imagen para que quede centrada y con un 
ancho y alto definido programaticamente algo así.

[Lo que se desea obtener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKl9U.png)

> ¿Alguna forma de  redimensionar de la imagen?

**EDICION**

Esta es una solucion tomando en cuenta lo recomendado por @Andrespengineer y haciendo uso de la clase `ConstraintSet` de esta forma pude lograr lo cometido quizas no sea lo mas viable pero de momento funciona.

Archivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/principal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

codigo Actividad:

```
int recurso = getResources().getIdentifier("alert", "drawable", getPackageName());

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setId(R.id.image);
imageView.setImageResource(recurso);

ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.principal);

ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams imageConstraint = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(imageConstraint);
constraintLayout.addView(imageView);

ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 400);
constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 400);
constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 400);
constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 400);

constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Comment: Puedes compartir tu archivo axml que define tu Layout? El problema puede ser en el ImageView y las propiedades asignadas.

Comment: @Andrespengineer en el archivo `xml ` no tengo declarado ningún ImageView, la imagen la obtengo programaticamente.

Comment: Prueba mi solucion y dejame saber si te funciona.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que a la hora de agregar mi solucion a tu codigo. Tu constraintLayout debe tener un background nulo o transparente. Ya que si agregas alguna imagen o color de fondo del constraint. No se podra visualizar la imagen que hay detras logicamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres agregar la propiedad `background` como fondo de un [Views](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) debes asegurarte que la imagen sea tenga las mismas dimensiones que la vista. De lo contrario perderá su escala y se vera muy estrecha o ampliada haciendo que pierda sus pixeles dependiendo de su tamaño.

Mi recomendación es que se cree un [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) que tenga las mismas dimensiones que la vista padre. [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) esta hecha para definir los recursos de imágenes por lo cual tiene propiedades que manipulen dichas imágenes con relación a la vista. Lo que necesitas es definir en tu layout un [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) que se adapte a tu vista padre. Definiendo un **orden Z** (superponer Views) con mayor profundidad que todos los elementos de tu vista.

Un layout que contenga un hijo contenedor de tipo `LinearLayout` no te deja superponer elementos ya que su orden es lineal. Por lo cual no podrias lograr establecer un ImageView con sus mismas dimensiones si hay mas hijos.

El truco esta en utilizar Layouts contenedores como `RelativeLayout` o `FrameLayout` los cuales si te dejan agregar hijos que definen un **orden Z** (superponer Views). Por ejemplo:

Programaticamente los [Views](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) tienen un metodo llamado `.bringToFront();` esto hace que el **orden Z** del hijo sea enviado al frente de todos. Si intentas hacer esto en un Layout que no sea de tipo contenedor. Simplemente hara que tu hijo establezca un orden del tipo del Layout. Por ejemplo el Lineal, lo envia al frente de los demas del **Orden X** y **Orden Y** si su orientacion es horizontal o vertical, respectivamente (porque es lineal).

Dicho esto tu solución debe ser la siguiente:

En el axml de tu Layout. Define un FrameLayout de modo que contenta tu vista decir, Tu `Constraintlayout` debe estar dentro del FrameLayout. Con propiedades de ancho y alto correspondiente. Ten en cuenta que `match_parent` se ajustara al tamaño del padre. `wrap_content` al tamaño que definan sus hijos.

Si es el primer hijo, agrega en tu layout para evitar error en el espacio xmlns:
`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/flContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/alert"/>
     . . .
          <!-- Aqui debe ir el ConstraintLayout -->
     . . .

</FrameLayout>
```

Si lo quieres hacer Programáticamente crea un [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) del tamaño de tu padre:

Inicializas el contenedor:

```
FrameLayout flContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.flContainer);

ImageView ivBackground = new ImageView(this); // this hace referencia al contexto

FrameLayout.LayoutParams fllp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

fllp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER; // Centrar la vista
ivBackground.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE); // Esto hara que la imagen se centre en el imageview que lo contiene, sin perder su escala
ivBackground.setLayoutParams(fllp);
```

Los parametros o `LayoutParams` deben ser del mismo tipo del que va a contener la vista. En este caso,  quien contiene dicha vista es el FrameLayout. Luego al contenedor que quieres agregar tu vista creada dinamicamente si hereda de [ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup) haces:

`flContainer.addView` ... este metodo tiene variantes que te permiten definir la posicion del View, los parametros (igualarlos a otros parametros de otra vista, etc...) u orden en el contenedor. En este caso, el primer hijo debe ser el ImageView, por lo tanto debes agregarlo en dicha posicion.

```
flContainer.addView(ivBackground, 0); // Esto hara que el Constraint quede encima de la imagen del background.
```

Puedes ver mas tipos de escala del [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) en este [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType). Por ejemplo si tu imagen es muy pequeña al hacerle `wrap_content`, puedes definir un tamaño fijo en `dp` en el `axml` y hacer `fitXY` pero ten en cuenta que perdera calidad si el tamaño es mas grande que tu imagen. Buena suerte.

Para setear la imagen una vez agregado el recurso dinamicamente:

```
ivBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.alert);
```

Comment: Gracias me ha servido, solo agregué algunas modificaciones, más tarde edito la respuesta por si gusta darle un visto. Saludos